# Laravel Many to Many (3 and 3+ Models) Design Questions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have got three models

> Contacts Model
>
> Contact Roles Model
>
> Project Model

Set up;

contacts can belong to multiple projects. (Many to Many)

each project has its own contact roles created by user. (One to Many - Roles are specific to projects)

Within selected project, a contact can be assigned to multiple roles (Many to many)

Tricky part is I have categories for roles model, when user is creating the role, they select a category for that role from a dropdown(from a db, total of 7 predefined categories).

Then what I try to do and have issue with understanding;

1.What is the best way to display all contacts with given roles on that specific project?

I can easily get `$project->contacts() //this gives me all contacts within that project`but I need to one step further, where I can get contacts with their roles.

2.Furthermore, how would I display all contacts that are part of that selected category for that project?

3.Should i be using a different connection between my models other than many to many, like has many through ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption - with

> display

you actually mean retrieve with eloquent.

Word of advice - READ THE DOCS! Laravel has great and easy to understand documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

> 1) I can easily get $project->contacts() //this gives me all contacts within that projectbut I need to one step further, where I can get contacts with their roles.

Nested eager loading:

```
$project = Project::with('contacts.roles')->find($id);
```

> 2) Furthermore, how would I display all contacts that are part of that selected category for that project?

Constraining eager loads and querying relationship existance:

```
$project = Project::with(['contacts', function($q) use ($categoryId) {
    $q->with('roles')->whereHas(['category' => function($q2) use ($categoryId) {
        $q2->whereId($categoryId);
    });
}]);
```

> 3.Should i be using a different connection between my models other than many to many, like has many through ?

Structure looks fine to me.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it actually cleaned up my controller.  As per displaying the retrieved data in my blade view files, I just do foreach statement correct? So for instance, if I want to show the name of my contact and their role next to it, 

`@foreach ($project->contacts as $contact)
{{$contact->firstname}}
{{$contact->contactrole->label }}
 @endforeach`

What if I have a second role for that specific contact? I should just do another foreach  within that foreach statement?

It is my first time coding within a framework, not so good with terminology. I will keep reading the docs.

Comment: Yup, you just do `@foreach ($project->contacts as $contact) {{ $contact->firstname }} @foreach ($contact->contactrole as $role) {{ $role->label }} @endforeach @endforeach`.

Comment: `@foreach ($project->contacts as $contact)
                    @foreach ($contact->contactrole as $role)
                    @if ($role->group == 'owner')
                    <li> {{$contact->firstname}} - {{$role->label}} </li>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach`
If the contact has say 2 role (say one owner, one team) - with above, I can list data in its related location on my page with that if check. But it will display itself two times, how can I prevent this? Or Should i be using your answer in question 2?

Comment: I'd say you have two roles for that `$contact` that have an owner group. Check your database. But that is no longer in the scope of this question, so you should ask a new question if you're still having problems.